# Trouble on running a Symfony Service

Tags: symfony, service

start working with symfony and got a problem with services.

...\app\config\services.yml

```
app.pdf.service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\PdfService
    arguments: [format, orientation]]
```

...\src\AppBundle\Service\PdfService.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class PdfService
{

    private $format;
    private $orientation;

    public function __construct($format, $orientation)
    {
        $this->format = $format;
        $this->orientation = $orientation;
    }

}
```

And now I try to use the service with:

```
$this->container->get('app.pdf.service');
```

Did I forgot something? $this->container->get( ist working, cause I invoked the tcpdf/Service from whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle. I will extends this service, cause I need much more functionality in it.

Any hint?
cu s00n
n00n

Comment: Got an Error Message?

Comment: `arguments: [format, orientation]]` -> surplus a bracket `]` ??

Comment: thx, but was just a copy and paste mistake. In my IDE the second bracket wassnt set.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error is: Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: What are `format, orientation`. Where have they been set or configured?

Comment: The error you report looks like a production environment error - do you have an error from Dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that format and orientation are well defined in your parameters, try :

```
app.pdf.service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\PdfService
    arguments: ["%format%", "%orientation%"]
```

An "hardcoded" definition example :

```
app.pdf.service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\PdfService
    arguments: ["a4", "landscape"]
```

Check official documentation for more detail : 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html#setting-up-the-container-with-configuration-files

Comment: no, it is not working, maybe something else to get configured before services are available. Seems that the service is not available within the container.